# Google Apps Domain Alias and POP

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email, pop3

I am considering setting up Google Apps for a client of mine. He has multiple domains and a domain alias will work fine for his needs. However, I have one question I haven't found an answer to.

Let's say I have the following email address:

```
example@primary-domain.com
examples@domain-alias.com
```

I can check `example@primary-domain.com` using POP without a problem. Is it possible to check `examples@domain-alias.com` as a separate POP account?

I believe I can setup Filters and/or Labels for the aliases in the webmail interface but can I have those go to separate pop accounts in my email client?